# NSLayoutConstraint causing programmatic toolbar to not show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have a programmatic **UIToolBar** that is created and drawn in the `viewWillAppear:` method of my certain ViewController. I have `NSLayoutConstraint` setup to keep my **toolbar** at the bottom of my screen and it works appropriately for iPhone 4s and 5s. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    keyboardSuggestionsOpen = NO;

    //Create custom UIToolBar
    commentToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    commentToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44); //108


    //[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    //Remove all contraints on the toolbar
    for(NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints)
        if(c.firstItem == commentToolBar || c.secondItem == commentToolBar)
            [self.view removeConstraint:c];

    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [self.commentToolBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


    commentToolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    commentToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    commentToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    //self.commentToolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    //self.commentsContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

    [commentTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22]];
    commentTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    commentTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 205, 35)];
    [commentTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [commentTextView.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];

    UIBarButtonItem *textViewItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:commentTextView];

    commentTextView.delegate = self;
    [commentTextView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

    commentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [commentButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 35)];
    [commentButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [commentButton.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
    [commentButton.layer setBorderWidth:0.75f];
    [commentButton.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"669900"]CGColor]];
    [commentButton setTitle:@"Comment" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    commentButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    [commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentButtonInvoked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    commentTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    commentTextView.text = @"Comment..";

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *commentButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:commentButton];
    [commentButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];

    [self.commentToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: textViewItem,flexSpace,commentButtonItem, nil] animated:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:commentToolBar];


    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(commentToolBar);
    NSString *format = @"V:[commentToolBar(==44)]-|";
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];

    [self.view layoutSubviews];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

As you can see I just programmatically added a **textView** and a **button** to the **toolbar**. The problem is that when it loads.. the **toolbar** doesn't even seem to be there(it's absent/invisible) and my **button** doesn't appear at all, however I know that the **textView** is in the right location because it appears at the bottom where it should be. Am I doing something wrong?

PS - I have provided a photo and a few more methods that may be pertinent to the loading/visibility of my **UIToolBar**

This is what it looks like after loading:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constraints on the toolbar are insufficient. You provide its height and its vertical position, but you have said nothing about where it should be horizontally. Thus, it ends up nowhere. Insufficient (ambiguous) constraints very typically come to one's attention when a view simply fails to appear in the interface — and so in your case.

Comment: I'm actually completely new to using an NSString to create a format for a constraint. I'm not sure how to actually add that to my `@"V:[commentToolBar(==44)]-|"`, also why is my textView drawn in the right place when it's frame is drawn, then added as subview to toolBar?

Comment: "I'm not sure how to actually add that" You add more constraints, in a separate line (or lines) of code.

Comment: "why is my textView drawn in the right place when it's frame is drawn, then added as subview to toolBar" Because the text view is not under the influence of auto layout. The toolbar is. The text view is positioned by frame. The toolbar is positioned by constraints. You got the frame right (or at least it looks right on _this_ size of screen). You got the constraints wrong.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought that perhaps I could just add something to the format string. Like I said I'm completely new to constraints. Thank you for the help, I'm testing this and setting it up as of right now.

Comment: You might want to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout